# Sliver AppBar not collapse when using listviewbuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

im so confuse why my sliverappbar doesnt collapse when i'm scrolling listviewbuilder

so what i want is Appbar will colapse but the bottom is pinned, also when im scrolling to up the appbar will show'n

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              snap: true,
              floating: true,
              expandedHeight: 150,
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text('mama'),
              bottom: AppBar(
                title: Container(
                  height: 45,
                  child: TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Enter a search term'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                    child: StreamBuilder<ListsetorModel>(
                        stream: con.resListsetor.stream,
                        builder: (_, snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                            if (snapshot.data!.result == null) {
                              return Center(
                                child: Text('Data kosong '),
                              );
                            } else {
                              return Scrollbar(
                                thickness: 5,
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.result!.length,
                                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      var formatDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd ')
                                          .format(snapshot
                                              .data!.result![index].createdAt!
                                              .toLocal());
                                      Result list =
                                          snapshot.data!.result![index];

                                      return InkWell(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          Navigator.push(
                                              context,
                                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                                  builder: (context) =>
                                                      DetailTransaksi(
                                                          kode: list.kode)));
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          child: Card(
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(9.0),
                                            ),
                                            child: Container(
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                    const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                                child: Column(
                                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                                  children: [
                                                    Container(
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .spaceBetween,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Text(
                                                            "Order ${list.kode}",
                                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                                fontWeight:
                                                                    FontWeight
                                                                        .bold),
                                                          ),
                                                          Text(formatDate),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                    Divider(),
                                                    Text(
                                                        "Please help us to confirm  \nto get 10% discount code for next order."),
                                                    SizedBox(
                                                      height: 10,
                                                    ),
                                                    Container(
                                                      child: Row(
                                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                                            MainAxisAlignment
                                                                .spaceBetween,
                                                        children: [
                                                          Container(
                                                            width: 96,
                                                            height: 36,
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xff85d057),
                                                            child: TextButton(
                                                              child: Row(
                                                                children: [
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                    width: 5,
                                                                  ),
                                                                  Text(
                                                                    "Qr Code",
                                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                                        color: Colors
                                                                            .white),
                                                                  ),
                                                                  SizedBox(
                                                                    height: 20,
                                                                    width: 20,
                                                                    child: Image
                                                                        .asset(
                                                                            'assets/images/qrscan.png'),
                                                                  )
                                                                ],
                                                              ),
                                                              onPressed: () {
                                                                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                                                                    context,
                                                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                                                        builder: (context) => Qrcode(
                                                                              data: list.kode!,
                                                                            )));
                                                              },
                                                            ),
                                                          ),
                                                      
                                                          )
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }),
                              );
                            }
                          }
                          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        }),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

so i want the sliverappbar collapse when im scroll thi listview, i tried adding physics neverscrollable on listview builder it doesn't work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so the answer is by adding in NestedScrollview

```
 floatHeaderSlivers: true,
```

and remove `snap: true` inside sliverappbar

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below code

```
class AnimatedAppBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const AnimatedAppBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedAppBarState createState() => _AnimatedAppBarState();
}

class _AnimatedAppBarState extends State<AnimatedAppBar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController stateController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode stateFocus = FocusNode();

  var animation;
  var controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder:
              (BuildContext context, bool innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
            if (innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
              /* Animation */
              controller = AnimationController(
                vsync: this,
                duration: Duration(
                  seconds: 1,
                ),
              );
              animation = Tween(
                begin: 0.0,
                end: 1.0,
              ).animate(controller);
              /* Animation */
              controller.forward();
            }
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 120.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                titleSpacing: 0.0,
                toolbarHeight: 90.0,
                centerTitle: false,
                elevation: 0.0,
                leadingWidth: 0.0,
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    if (innnerBoxIsScrolled != null &&
                        innnerBoxIsScrolled == true)
                      FadeTransition(
                        opacity: animation,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Search",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                autovalidateMode:
                                    AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                /* autovalidate is disabled */
                                controller: stateController,
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                                      RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                                      r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                                ],
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                maxLength: 160,
                                onChanged: (val) {},
                                maxLines: 1,
                                validator: (value) {},
                                focusNode: stateFocus,
                                autofocus: false,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  errorMaxLines: 3,
                                  counterText: "",
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        width: 1,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      )),
                                  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Search" ?? "",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 6.0,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                // bottom: PreferredSize(
                //   preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(5.0),
                //   child: Text(''),
                // ),
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                horizontal: 8.0,
                              ),
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: [
                                  Text(
                                    "Search",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 24.0,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                        "https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/2TRIFRwcjrTuNprkTQHVxs/088159eb8e811aaac789c24701d7fdb1/LP_image.jpg?fit=fill&w=632&h=354&fm=webp"), //NetworkImage
                                    radius: 16.0,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                autovalidateMode:
                                    AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                /* autovalidate is disabled */
                                controller: stateController,
                                inputFormatters: [
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(
                                      RegExp(r"\s\s")),
                                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp(
                                      r'(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])')),
                                ],
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                maxLength: 160,
                                onChanged: (val) {},
                                maxLines: 1,
                                validator: (value) {},
                                focusNode: stateFocus,
                                autofocus: false,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  errorMaxLines: 3,
                                  counterText: "",
                                  filled: true,
                                  fillColor: Colors.white,
                                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Color(0xffE5E5E5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                                        width: 1,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      )),
                                  focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                    borderRadius:
                                        BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      width: 1,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  hintText: "Search" ?? "",
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Text("Index value: $index"),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Nested Scroll with Tab Bar

```
class NestedScrollWithTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  const NestedScrollWithTabs({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NestedScrollWithTabsState createState() => _NestedScrollWithTabsState();
}

class _NestedScrollWithTabsState extends State<NestedScrollWithTabs>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  var animation;
  var controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: NestedScrollView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            headerSliverBuilder: (headerCtx, innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
              if (innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
                /* Animation */
                controller = AnimationController(
                  vsync: this,
                  duration: Duration(
                    seconds: 1,
                  ),
                );
                animation = Tween(
                  begin: 0.0,
                  end: 1.0,
                ).animate(controller);
                /* Animation */
                controller.forward();
              }

              return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  expandedHeight: ScreenUtil().setHeight(185.0),
                  floating: false,
                  pinned: true,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  titleSpacing: 0.0,
                  centerTitle: true,
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  leadingWidth: 0.0,
                  title: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                    
                      if (innnerBoxIsScrolled != null &&
                          innnerBoxIsScrolled == true)
                        FadeTransition(
                          opacity: animation,
                          child: Text(
                            "Title",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 22,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                     
                    ],
                  ),
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    background: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                          children: [
                            Image.network(
                              "https://images.pexels.com/photos/10181294/pexels-photo-10181294.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" ??
                                  "",
                              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                              height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(126.0),
                              width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                              filterQuality: FilterQuality.low,
                              loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                  Widget child,
                                  ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                                if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                                return Container(
                                  height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(126.0),
                                  width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                );
                              },
                              errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
                                return SizedBox(
                                  height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(126.0),
                                  width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                            Positioned(
                              top: ScreenUtil().setHeight(92.0),
                              // left: ScreenUtil().setWidth(20.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  CircleAvatar(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                    radius: 30.0,
                                    child: ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                                        45.0,
                                      ),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/10181294/pexels-photo-10181294.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" ??
                                            "",
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                        height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(72.0),
                                        width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                        filterQuality: FilterQuality.low,
                                        loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                                            Widget child,
                                            ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                                          if (loadingProgress == null)
                                            return child;
                                          return Container(
                                            height:
                                                ScreenUtil().setHeight(72.0),
                                            width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                          );
                                        },
                                        errorBuilder:
                                            (context, error, stackTrace) {
                                          return SizedBox(
                                            height:
                                                ScreenUtil().setHeight(72.0),
                                            width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                            child: Container(
                                              width: ScreenUtil().screenWidth,
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Text("Name"),
                                  Text("Place"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                  handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                      headerCtx),
                  sliver: SliverPersistentHeader(
                    delegate: SliverAppBarDelegate(TabBar(
                      labelColor: Colors.blue,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                      labelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                      unselectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                      ),
                      labelPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      indicatorColor: Colors.blue,
                      indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          text: "Tab 1",
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: "Tab 2",
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
                    pinned: false,
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                /* Tab 1 */
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 100,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                        child: Text("Index value: $index"),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                /* Tab 2 */
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 10,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                        child: Text("Index value of Tab 2: $index"),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  SliverAppBarDelegate(this.tabBars);

  final TabBar tabBars;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 60.0;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 60.0;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    // shinkOffsetPerValue.value = shrinkOffset;
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          tabBars,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your answer , yes thats work perfectly but thats not what i want its littlebit complex, so i found my asnwer after i tried

Comment: what is your answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact solution after days. you have to put as background the silver component.

```
FlexibleSpaceBar(
  background: Widget() // Repleace Widget
)
```

Full Code is below.

```
    NestedScrollView(
            floatHeaderSlivers: true,
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            body: ListView(), // Repleace ListView
            headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) =>
                [
              SliverAppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Widget() // Repleace Widget
                )
               )
    )
```