# How to achieve nested SliverList in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I want to achieve the following in Flutter:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    NestedSlivers(
      slivers: [
         SliverListOutside(
           child: SliverListInside()
         )
      ])
   ]
)
```

Currently I'm using Slivers with ShrinkWrappingViewport but its performing very badly. So any help or clue would be very useful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please  can you elaborate what you actually want to do

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70493660/15215450 link

Comment: @Manishyadav I actually have a ListView inside another ListView with shrinkwrap set to true. Now the app freezes a few seconds while loading the nested scrollview. I tried replacing it with SliverList but still expecting error without setting the shrinkwrap to true.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `NestedScrollView` to achieve the same.

Here's an example for the same:-

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
     appBar: SliverAppBar(),
      body: new NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            new SliverAppBar(
              pinned: true,
              title: new Text('App Bar'),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new FlutterLogo(size: 100.0, colors: Colors.purple),
            new Container(
              height: 300.0,
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: 60,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Text('Item No. $index');
                },
              ),
            ),
            new FlutterLogo(size: 50.0, colors: Colors.red),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I updated my question to clarify what I want to achieve.